# jQuery target td header attribute

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have the following html

```
<table>
  <tr>
    <td headers="Monday"> <div class="foo"> Some stuff </div> </td>
    <td headers="Tuesday"> <div class="foo"> Some stuff </div> </td>
    <td headers="Wednesday"> <div class="foo"> Some stuff </div> </td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

How can I target the td with Monday headers and remove .foo?

Comment: you are missing `=` in `headers"Monday"`, it should be `headers="Monday"`

Comment: can you explain what you need again?

Comment: Sorry guys. Some typo. Edited now.

Comment: can you simply say what you want to do in plain english? cause the explanation and the code snippet together seems confusing

Comment: it will be better if you can share the desired markup after the script is executed

Comment: Edited now. That's as simple as it can be.

Comment: $('td[headers="Monday"]').find('> div').removeClass('foo')

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Is this what you meant?

[***DEMO***](http://jsfiddle.net/zd3MF/)

```
if ($(".foo").text().indexOf('Monday') != -1) {
    $("td[headers='Monday']").find(".foofoo").remove();
}
```

Comment: You are a star! This is EXACTLY what I need. Thank you for deciphering through my message. lol

Answer (score 1):

You can remove class with something like this:

```
$('td[headers="Monday"] > div').removeClass('foo');
```

**Demo:** http://jsfiddle.net/8qbba/

Comment: @vsync Congratulations! You've won the prize :)

Comment: it's not about me, it's about respecting other people and not posting the same answer again..

Comment: @vsync has a thought occurred to you that I might not have seen your comment? Perchance it was hidden under "Show more comments... section?" Or perhaps I began to test and write the answer at the same time you were writing your comment? Never mind, I confess I did plagiarize your comment. I did the same for all my 17K points, but finally you caught me. Congratulations! You've won the prize :)

Answer (score 1):

`$('div','td[headers=Monday]').remove();`

**[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/SUfAK/)**

Answer (score 0):

Try this...

```
if($('.foo:contains("Monday")')){
    $('table').each(function(){
        var mondayHeader = $(this).find('tr.td[headers="Monday"]');
        $(mondayHeader).closest('div').removeClass('foofoo');
    });
}
```